# Angular - Custom Input: reset touched state via form.reset() not working

Tags: angular

i've got a question regarding resetting a Form with a Custom Input on it.

I bound my validation messages to the touched property of my inputs.
While on default Inputs the form.reset() also resets the touched state back to false, on custom inputs, its not forwarded.

I've added a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ZyELDDFf3rxQRipHlWnb?p=preview to illustrate the problem: touch and leave both controls, both are touched: true, afterwards reset.
How can i forward this clearing reset event, which reverts the touched state back to false, to my Custom Input?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <p><span class="boldspan">Form data:</span>{{demoForm.value | json}}</p>
    <p><span class="boldspan">Model data:</span> {{dataModel}}</p>
    <form #demoForm="ngForm">
      <custom-input name="someValue" [(ngModel)]="dataModel">
        custom input
      </custom-input>
      <label>native input<br>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="someOtherValue" name="someOtherValue"
      #sOV="ngModel"></label>
      <div>touched: {{sOV.touched}}</div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button (click)="demoForm.reset()">Reset Form</button>`
})
export class App {
    dataModel: string = '';
}
```

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
demoForm.resetForm()
```

rather than

```
demoForm.reset()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the Problem i have.